# Bluetooth transfer between iOS and Android?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, bluetooth, gamekit

I was just wondering if it is possible to develop apps on both the iOS and Android that will allow bluetooth file transfer between the two platforms? I have looked at different bluetooth API's such as Game Kit, and I have not figured out a way to do it.

Please let me know if any of you out there have done this in the past.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: even i am searching fro the same

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible under iOS.
Because sharing files an an iOS device is not able without special apps ! The only thing that is possible, so far as I have heard is that you could use GameKit to implement you own bluetooth file exhange between 2 devices.
But simply as that sharing between ios and android is not possible.

Comment: Would there be any other way to implement some sort of file transfer without the need of data? for example, would there be the possibility of transfering files using wifi (without connecting to any wireless network)?

Comment: I'm not sure but there is a way with the iPhone that you can open a WLAN hotspot on your iPhone device. Maybe there could be a way !